# The type org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, java-11, java-module, eclipse-2018-12

I am using ASM 7.0 in a short Java 11 project, which convert a class file to a text using the following code:

```
final var charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (var pw = new PrintWriter(bos, false, charset)) {
  final org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor traceClassVisitor = new TraceClassVisitor(null,
      new org.objectweb.asm.util.Textifier(), new PrintWriter(bos));
  new ClassReader(stream.getStream()).accept(traceClassVisitor,
      ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_CODE | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
}
```

This works, however from times to times, Eclipse produce an error: *The type org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*. Clean and compile fixes the issue.

When built with Maven 3.6.0 + Java 11, there are no such errors.

My `module-info.java` is the following:

```
module stackoverflow.asm {
  exports stackoverflow.asm;
  // requires ransitive org.objectweb.asm;
  // requires transitive org.objectweb.asm.tree;
  requires transitive org.objectweb.asm.util;
  // requires transitive org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis;
  uses java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider;
}
```

In maven, I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

While I understand the problem reported by Eclipse,  `org.objectweb.asm.util.Textifier` requires the class `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor`, but Eclipse fail to find it in the classpath (or should I say module path ?).

Is it a bug of Eclipse (I am using latest) or am I missing something in my `module-info.java` ?

**Note:** as said, I understand the error; I already had it in the past, when using maven dependencies with bad transitive or no dependencies, or simply when uninstalling the JDK in an already compiled project. This was relatively easy to fix, but here I don't know how.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `requires org.objectweb.asm` for accessing the `ClassVisitor`? Or rather `requires org.objectweb.asm.util` which itself already `requires transitive org.objectweb.asm;`. In terms of Eclipse, if its failing to find the class, it might be failing to find it in neither classpath(unnamed module) not modulepath(named modules).

Comment: I’d say, when a clean build can fix it, it can’t be a problem of a wrong setup. Unless you have made problematic changes yourself, like modifying something in the file system outside Eclipse, I tend to say, Eclipse shouldn’t get into the state of needing a clean build or at least, detect it itself and do the necessary steps, so it looks much like an Eclipse bug.

Comment: All of that compile using openjdk. And the commented requires are all tries (it failed). Note: my Eclipse was run with Java 8. Don't know if that change anything (I use Java 8 to run maven project, and toolchain to compile).